# WPF Conditional Binding when backing object is NULL

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, binding

So i have a TextBlock like below where i am displaying a name in the middle with the binding Name.

```
<TextBlock>
    <Run Text="Hello"/> <Run Text="{Binding Name}" /><Run Text=","/>
</TextBlock>
```

Is there any way to put a condition here to that when 'Name' is null or even better if the current DataContext object is null then i dont display anything at all?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conditional text binding XAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28817250/conditional-text-binding-xaml)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can update the style of your `TextBlock` by setting the `Visibility` to `Hidden` or `Collapsed` to hide it. Just add a `DataTrigger` for the case of an empty string like `Value=""` and a null value like `Value="{x:Null}` bound to the `Name` property:

```
<TextBlock.Style>
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Name}" Value="">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Name}" Value="{x:Null}">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</TextBlock.Style>
```