# Dynamic Path in Treeview TextBlock

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, treeview

I am trying to change the Path in WPF Treeview TextBlock dynamically via user selection i.e. dropdown. Upon user interaction the path should take predefined values i.e. `Name, Type, Order`.

```
<TreeView x:Name="Main" ItemsSource="{Binding Items, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}"   >
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type models:Root}" 
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" /> <--- Dynamically change this
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

In C# there is an `BindingExpression` helper class however I am not clear how to use it in ViewModel scenario

Comment: A MultiBinding may work. There is however not enough information for a detailed answer.

Comment: Not sure how Multibinding might work as it will show all the Binded properties. However I need to show just the selected one. Unless there is a way to implment an IF statment.

Comment: That is a misconception. A MultiBinding's Converter could select the desired property value.

Comment: your response here was eyeopening https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28817250/conditional-text-binding-xaml/28817452 ..

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the actual binding *path*, you need to do this programmatically. You cannot dynamically change the binding path in XAML.

A better option would be to change the *value* of the source property based on the selection in the `ComboBox`, or use a `Style` with triggers. Something like this:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type models:Root}" 
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children}">
    <ContentControl>
        <ContentControl.Style>
            <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedValue}" Value="Name">
                        <Setter Property="Content">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    ...
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ContentControl.Style>
    </ContentControl>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```